# How to disable a button after print in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, printing

I got this code for direct print

```
 Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    With AxEDOffice1
        .SetActivePrinter("Microsoft XPS Document Writer")
        .PrintOut(EDOfficeLib.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument)
        '.PrintDialog()
    End With
End Sub
```

and I have this picture.. How to disable the print button after print is done?.

[image]

For the Information I am following this [LINK](https://www.edrawsoft.com/embed-word-vbnet.php) on how to browse MS Word and Print, ETC.

Comment: Do you want to disable the button immediately after the Print job is sent to the printer - or after the print job is completed? What should happen if the printer doesn't report status information back to the software? What if the user chooses the "Print to file" feature in Windows? What if the user uses a virtual-printer like Acrobat or XPS or OneNote?

Comment: @Dai I included the link where I am following.. For your questions.. Maybe I want to disable the button after the print job is completed.

Comment: The image you posted is absolutely useless and unnecessary. Why would we need to know what your app looks like? As far as your question, you were asked to clarify it by @Dai. Maybe when you figure out what it is you want to ask and [edit] your question to make it clear, you'll get an answer. Expecting us to follow a link to understand it, or saying that *Maybe I want to disable the button after...* is not going to work. What **specifically** do you want to do? Not what you think you **might** want to do, but what **specifically do you want to do**?

Comment: All I want to achieve in this post is to **disable** a button after the print job is completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is setting `Enabled` property

```
Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
With AxEDOffice1
    .SetActivePrinter("Microsoft XPS Document Writer")
    .PrintOut(EDOfficeLib.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument)

End With

BtnPrint.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I will try it later.

Comment: @KiRa waiting your feedback :)